# Spring Data Rest gives GC overhead exceeded

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-rest

**EDITED**

There are 2 entities User and RefSecQuestion linked as below -

Inside User : This was changed to EAGER to Work around [Bug](http://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-269)

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question", nullable = false)
    public RefSecQuestion getRefSecQuestion() {
        return this.refSecQuestion;
}
```

Inside RefSecQuestion :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "refSecQuestion")
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}
```

Visiting URL -  /api/refSecQuestions  or /api/users/2/refSecQuestions give this error -

```
 11:25:14,320 WARN LoadContexts.cleanup():115 - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@32f6b537<rs=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet@72b935ef>
2014-10-19 11:25:14.522:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1075697729-17: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1280)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:958)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.generateEntityKey(AbstractSessionImpl.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getCollectionOwner(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:694)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.findCollectionOwner(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.finishUpRow(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1897)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.isEmpty(PersistentSet.java:166)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler$1.doWithAssociation(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:337)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.getEmbeddedResources(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController$1.apply(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController$1.apply(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.doWithReferencedProperty(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:464)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report, not a question.

Comment: Is there a workaround for avoiding this GC error in Spring data Rest and I am not entirely sure if GC overrun is directly related to that bug ?

Comment: No idea, but you are presenting two separate issues (serializable ID issues and GC issue) without offering any reason to think they are related. If you are specifically concerned with the GC issue then consider focusing your question on that, or else connecting it to the serializable ID issue.

Comment: Doing the edits to focus on GC issue only

Comment: User model itself has about 20 @OneToMany relations as well with other table which is Fetch Type LAZY, just for facts. I don't however think that should matter for URL to RefSecQuestion which is only ManyToOne relation in User

Comment: related link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451920/pagination-in-spring-data-rest-for-nested-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GC overhead limit exceeded` means you run out of memory when using the CMS garbage collector. This can either be due to a memory leak or your application simply having a larger live dataset than your VM options allow. To figure out the issue use

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

and possibly `-XX:HeapDumpPath` (check [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) for more information). Then run a tool like [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to figure out what the issue is. There are also several commercial tools available like [Plumbr](https://plumbr.eu).

Comment: i found that when the resultset of Spring Data REST is very big, this is happening leading to OutOfMemory. However, all my repositories are extending JPARepository. I don't understand how default pagination is not happening which should limit first page result to 20 only

Comment: Why do you expect pagination to happen? Can you post your repository?

Comment: added the repositories in related link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451920/pagination-in-spring-data-rest-for-nested-resources